# GAE, memcache before DB update

Tags: google-app-engine, memcached

I have some troubles with memcache and GAE DB operations.
if i update memcache rigth after DB operations, x.put(), for example, my memcache function  often return old value. If i use sleep(), cache more often correct, but this is not right, in my opinion

```
sleep(0.2) 
data = Picture.all().order('-created').fetch(300)
memcache.set('pictures_all', data)
```

What i need to do, to get correct memcache?

**ANSWER:**
Need to use parent with query, all Picture entities must have same parent, then you get strong consistant results

```
data = Picture.all().order('-created').ancestor(main_key()).fetch(300)
memcache.set('pictures_all', data)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have the data, just update one entry in the memcache, no need to retrieve all from memcache. Something like

```
data.put()
memcache.set(key, data)
```

Comment: not really good in my case. Is there a way to wait, before DB is updated, and after get a correct values?

Comment: why is it not really good? If you only update one entity, why do you need to fetch all the data? It will be more efficient to update one entry in your memcache to reflect the changes

Comment: its prototype, i just need correct caching on update, its enough at this time, without complexity. When i will be behind of appspot quotes, i definitely use your more advanced way of caching, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
config = db.create_config(deadline=10, read_policy=db.STRONG_CONSISTENCY)
data = Picture.all().order('-created').fetch(300, config=config)
memcache.set('pictures_all', data)
```

I guess, this is solution.

EDIT: No, this is dont work

Comment: Don't you want it the other way?
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass#Query_fetch

read_policy
Read policy specifying desired level of data consistency:
STRONG_CONSISTENCY
Guarantees the freshest results, but limited to a single entity group.
EVENTUAL_CONSISTENCY
Can span multiple entity groups, but may occasionally return stale results.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track that the problem is with eventual consistency.

Using STRONG_CONSISTENCY does solve the problem, but it'll give you scalability problems down the road - ones that will be difficult to resolve.

The solution for this is, annoyingly, more complex than it should be.  I'm also not sure whether there's really a bulletproof solution given the eventual consistency behavior.

pseudocode should look something like this:

```
all_pictures = memcache.get('pictures_all')
if not all_pictures:
    all_pictures = convert_to_list(Picture.all().order('-created').fetch(300))
if not newdata in all_pictures:
    add_to_list_in_proper_order(all_pictures, newdata)
memcache.set('pictures_all', all_pictures)
```

Answer (score 0):

Great.

I had the same problem and the solution was exactly what asker gave: the use of ancestors

To read:

```
data = Picture.all().order('-created').ancestor(main_key()).fetch(300)
```

To save:

```
pic = Picture(parent=main_key(), ...)
pic.put()
```

Comment: But depends on if Pictures are or aren't more readed than writed, I said that because with the use of ancestors, only 1 write per second is allowed to all the ancestor group.