# Strange memcache behaviour on GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, memcached

I'm doing a simple CRUD system with memcache to make reads of tables faster, but I'm a bit confused with the behaviour.

Basically, this is the important code:

```
class Book(db.Model):
    title = db.StringProperty(required=True)


@classmethod
def getAll(cls):
    key = 'booklist'
    books = memcache.get(key)
    if books is None:
        logging.info('DB access for key %s.', key)
        books = Book.all().order("title").fetch(100)
        if not memcache.set(key, books, 300):
            logging.error('Memcache set failed for key %s.', key)
    else:
        logging.info('Memcache for key %s.', key)
    return books


# Save a Book and return it
@classmethod
def save(cls, title):
    book = Book(title=title)
    book.put()
    # Flush memcache for this key
    if memcache.delete('booklist') != 2:
        logging.error('Memcache delete failed')
    return book
```

In the app code I can add a book, so, once I get the title from the form, I do this:

```
    book = Book.save(title)
    if book is None:
        logging.error('Book save error.')

    self.redirect("/showBooks")
```

The last redirect gets me to this code:

```
    def get(self):
        books = Book.getAll()
        self.renderPage("listBooks.htm", data=books)
```

Which only get all the books and display it on a table. The problem is that the steps are executed so quickly, or something like that, because the save function flushes the cache (it appears in the log), the getAll function writes in the log 'DB access for key booklist' but nothing appears in the table, like if GAE were still saving the data in the datastore and the new element have no time to be readed.
And, if you just wait 15 seconds and refresh the page, then the data is there.

I've tried other thing: instead of save and inmediately refresh the page with the redirection, I made an "intermediate info page" with the message "successfully saved". If I go to the listing page from this intermediate page, without touching any other code, all works fine (the new data appears in the table, like was expected). Again, this makes me to think that GAE needs time to save the object and my immediate read I was doing originally is faster.

Obviously, if I flush manually the memcache, in the next page refresh all the new data appears.

Can this be true? My read is faster than the GAE write and is this the problem I'm having?

Comment: Finally I found here the solution to the problem: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15846971/gae-memcache-before-db-update?rq=1) Basically, to be fast, you need to use an ancestor. I didn't use one because Book was my first object, and I still don't understand well the use of ancestors.

Comment: I would recommend you to use ndb instead (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/). Ndb has automatic cache via memcache, and many other features.

Comment: HRD eventual consistancy answers why you don't see the item just added, but it doesn't explain why other older Book entities are missing.

Comment: Thanks @Sebastian. I'm reading now thath docs. Sounds great.

Comment: @Tim, I have a list of Books, so when I add one I want to refresh my list. It seems that the problem was the speed at GAE save without an ancestor. Maybe so slow and the immediate read was faster. But using the ancestor all works.

Comment: OK, I misunderstood what you originally said.  This is a result of eventual consistancy with the HRD.  As you have found out you need to perform ancestor queries or you could just add it to your result set in memcache rather than flushing the cache.

Comment: Thanks @TimHoffman, I will try your recommendation of modify memcache instead of flush it, but I'm reading about NDB and it seems a better solution.

Comment: Absolutely, I would go with ndb if you are just starting out.  However ndb doesn't cache queries. Have a look at caching in ndb for a full rundown.  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/cache